# CLLocationManager updates location with inaccurate coordinates

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

My code is for a Golf player app. I need the exact user location here is my present code

```
- (void) update_location
{
  locationManager_player = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager_player.delegate = self;
    locationManager_player.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
        [locationManager_player requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [locationManager_player startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
// Code to handle the current user location
}
```

The above delegate method is not giving the exact user location. Perhaps this gives the coordinates which are 30 to 40 yards far from user current position

Thanks in advance

Comment: show some additional code

Comment: How you requesting for location updates? Please update question to include code.

Comment: where is your code ? show us what you already tried ?

Comment: Even using `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` will never guarantee absolutely precise locations.

Comment: @PratikPrajapati  locationManager_player = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager_player.delegate = self;
        locationManager_player.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
            [locationManager_player requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        }
        [locationManager_player startUpdatingLocation];

Answer (score 0):

Location accuracy is controlled by the `desiredAccuracy` property of `CLLocationManager`. Check what is set in your case. Default value is `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`. You can set it to `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` but it require more power requirements.

More detail [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423836-desiredaccuracy).

Comment: locationManager_player = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager_player.delegate = self;
        locationManager_player.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
            [locationManager_player requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        }
        [locationManager_player startUpdatingLocation];